# Yii2 - Selenium Standalone Server using ChromeDriver error

Tags: php, selenium, yii2, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I have installed Selenium and ChromeDriver.

I used to launch server and locate driver.

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
```

and then launched ChromeDriver with

```
./chromedriver
```

When i run

```
codecept run
```

I get

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] Timed out 
waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-
29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'kyle-pc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.39-1-MANJARO', java.version: 
1.8.0_141'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I had missed a line from config of acceptance.suite.yml. Added 
`port: 9515` to `-WebDriver`.